# Showing a product of two Lebesgue integrals is $\geq 1$ if the product of the integrands is $\geq 1$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces, holder-inequality

Let $\mu$ be a probability measure on a set $X$, i.e. $\mu(X)=1$, and let $f$ and $g$ be positive measurable functions on $X$.  Show that if $fg\geq1$, then the integral of $f$ times the integral of $g$ is greater than or equal to $1$.

I'm not sure how to approach this.  Since $f$ and $g$ are positive, the integral of $f$ and the integral of $g$ are equal to the $L_1$ norm of $f$ and the $L_1$ norm of $g$, but I'm not sure why $fg\geq 1$ implies that the product of their $L_1$ norms is greater than or equal to $1$.  Considering that $fg$ is involved, I was thinking of using Holder's inequality, but I'm not sure what $p$ and $q$ to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This relies more on an arithmetic trick than on analysis. Since $fg \ge 1$ you have also that $\sqrt{fg} \ge 1$ so that $$1 \le \int_X \sqrt{fg} \le \left(\int_X f \right)^{1/2} \left( \int_X g \right)^{1/2}$$ by Holder's inequality. Now square both sides.

Comment: I don't understand your application of Holder's inequality.  What are your $p$ and $q$?

Comment: $2$ and $2$. $\mbox{}$

Comment: And how do we know that $\sqrt f$ and $\sqrt g$ are in $L_2$?

Comment: You don't. Since $f$ and $g$ are positive the integrals are all defined, even if possibly infinite.

Comment: OK, thanks for your answer.